# How does Gluon mobile paid license work?

Tags: javafx, gluon

I understand that Gluon shows nag screen for free users as per the documentation on the websiteand removes the nag for paid. "Licenses are validated online once per application install."

Say, a developer purchases a paid subscription, builds and releases the app in 6 months. After the app is released there wont be development for a long time.

So, the developer cancels the paid account and goes back to free. The app is already released and in stores and on many users devices. Now, after the six month, will the nag screen start showing again for new installs and current users?

Comment: AFAIK, once you have an app released using a license version, it will never show a nag screen. However, the better forum to ask such questions would be http://gluonhq.com/about-us/contact-us/ .

Comment: I asked them but they never replied back. I just got an automated response. Wonder if this project has anyone supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked technical support about this problem and their answer was:

> Hi Ahmed,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Any apps deployed to App Store or Play Store with the license will continue to work without nag screen even after the license expires. Only, if you want to make any changes(development) to the existing app after the expiry of the license, the nag screen will be shown again.
>
> Hope it answers your question.